# Hiding action bar icon under tree dots

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an action bar where I have an icon of my choice. I want this icon to appear under three dots icon, which appears only as a result of overflow of action bar, when it lacks space. I want my action bar icon appear only as a sub menu of three dots button, not as a top level icon. How should I achieve this? Can I force this three dots icon to appear always in action bar, regardless of how many icons fit?

Comment: Mine is not a direct answer to your question, but I would like to recommend you the Action Bar Sherlock. Download it, it comes with a lot of good examples which they make things like the one you want. Everybody loves it. I'm pretty sure this gonna help you a lot!

Comment: I use ABS in my project, but how does this help since it just implements the same action bar behavior for older platforms?

Answer (score 1):

In your menu's XML, add `android:showAsAction="never"`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/always_in_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/your_menu_item_title"/>
```

Comment: if a phone has a settings hardware button, this won't help

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov - if you have a settings hardware button, there is no three dots icon. Ever. Adding `showAsAction="never"` always means that your icon will not appear on the Action Bar, whether that overflow menu appears when you hit a hardware button or when you hit an on screen overflow menu button. See [the design doc](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out a bit later. That's why I added three dots icon manually.